# Excel Add-in C# oracle connection. Is it secure?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

I have created an Excel 2007 add-in using Visual Studio 2008 and built-in project template. In my project, I have a database connection class that connects to an Oracle database with a connection string, such as:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=ibd1.dev;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;";
```

My question is, how safe is this after the add-in is deployed.  Is it possible for an end user (or mischievous hacker) to decompile the add-in and see the connection string?  I can't risk that if it is possible.

I should mention how it is deployed.  I am using the "Publish" function in Visual Studio to put the installation files out on a shared network drive that anyone inside the company can access.  The resulting directory has a setup.exe, a VSTO file, and a couple sub directories with DLL's and MANIFEST files.  I don't have much experience with deployment since I am typically a web app developer.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for an end user (or mischievous hacker) to decompile the add-in and see the connection string? I can't risk that if it is possible.

Yes. Tools like Reflector, [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), etc make that trivial.

I probably wouldn't connect directly to a database from a VSTO Add In. Instead, I would call a web service (which talks to the DB), and the user would need to authenticate to the web service, either with a username and password, Windows Integrated Authentication, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I didn't think of a web service in this case.  I think that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's easy to decompile it, but you could [encrypt your connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28VS.80%29.aspx) to reduce problems. But if it's not standalone application you could use database from the server side services.

Answer (score 1):

As with all .NET applications, the DLL's can be very easily decompiled, which would expose the connection string and password in plain text.  You can test this yourself within minutes by downloading a free decompiler (I suggest http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

.NET has features for encrypting connection strings, try documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx